# Change generic types view at swagger

Tags: java, swagger

For example, i have generic class

```
Human<Carl>
```

And this class looks like

```
Human<<Carl>>
```

at swagger .json generated by app.
How can i change brackets from <<>> to [] view? So class in .json would look like

```
Human[Carl]
```

I'm using Docket(springfox) to configurate api information.

Comment: Can you share more details ? Are you using swagger annotations or something else ? What Annotations ?

Comment: i ve tried any of this - swagger annotations like ApiModelProperty, ApiModel etc, Docket api to configuration like alternateTypeRules() - but none of this works